# Camera controls not visible on iOS 7

Tags: ios

I have used Image Picker Controller to call device camera. The code listed below works fine below iOS 7. But when I use the Same code on iOS 7 to launch camera I am unable see "Use" and "Cancel" buttons.

```
- (void)getCameraPicture {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Any help is appreciated.
[image: Please find the screenshot to see the problem]

**Update:**

When I try to run this code in a sample app then it works fine.(sample app contains single view). But when I put it inside my project the buttons doesn't show.

Answer (score 2):

in the code should be there:

```
 ...

 picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

have you checked this `@property (nonatomic) BOOL showsCameraControls` in UIImagePickerController.